# Rough rule of thumb for when to use $N$ and when to use $N-1$ when calculating variance.

Tags: statistics, variance, standard-deviation

I don't really understand the whole concept of estimators and biased/unbiased etc with regards to calculating the standard deviation.

Is there a rough rule of thumb that I can use to know when I should use one over the other ?

I mean does it depend on the magnitude of $N$ or the nature of the data or what ?

Comment: See [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17890/what-is-the-difference-between-n-and-n-1-in-calculating-population-variance)   In brief you use $N$ when the mean is known (as it would be if you had the entire population in the data) and you use $N-1$ when the mean is unknown (as it would be if all you have is some sample data).

Comment: As another reference, read the section on sample variance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator#Sample_variance)

Comment: @lulu Would you ever use $N-1$ if you knew the mean of the population ?

Comment: I can't think of such a situation.  Switching to $N-1$ is a correction for the bias introduced by using the same data to estimate $\textit {both}$ the mean and the variance.  If you have the mean from some other source (or if you know a priori that the sample mean is exact) then there is no such bias.

Comment: Worth remarking:  As a practical matter,  If your sample (or population) size is so small that this correction is significant, then you should know in advance that all these statistical measures are going to be bad. Even with just $100$ data points the difference is only about $1\%$.